# Executing a command-line .exe file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exe

I have a .exe file converted from a .jar.
It is a command based application, so I have to start it with a batch script. Here is the batch script:

```
@echo off
cd C:\desktop\plant-text-adventure-win
start planttextadventure
pause
```

When I double click on the batch script, this happens: `Windows could not find 'planttextadventure'.  Please confirm if you have input the correct name and retry.`

I don't know what is happening, I have no idea about `cmd` as I use Mac, but I can confirm I have an executable called `planttextadventure.exe` in a folder called `plant-text-adventure-win`.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test your batch file by executing it within a shell.

Simply enter within the start menu the command `cmd` to open up a shell. Within this black box you could now simply enter the commands from your batch script and lookout for some error message.

If you look at your script I would guess that the `cd` command (to change the current directory) is not correct. Maybe you should replace it with

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\plant-text-adventure-win
```

because the desktop folder is on a default installation not directly under the root drive but within the user profile available.

Another solution to get this thing to work, is by opening the windows explorer, going to the .exe file you wish to execute and drag & drop the .exe file **with a right mouse click** onto the desktop.

Then a context menu appears and you select the option *Create shortcut here*.

Comment: It's very weird. When I tried the thing you told me, I was able to change to `Desktop` but not `plant-text-adventure-win`. Even weirder, plant-text-adventure-win was right on my desktop. Would it be like that because I am using a Virtual Machine?

Comment: Maybe the folder is not on your desktop, but only a shortcut to it and the folder itself resides somewhere else on your machine. But that's all wild guessing. AFAIK it doesn't matter if you run it within a VM or directly on your hardware.